# How do I use Proguard to optimize a War file?

Tags: java, optimization, jar, proguard

I have an application in `.war` archive which I'm trying to optimize in size and performance and I heard about Proguard.

On https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard Readme it says:

> Building ProGuard is easy - you'll just need a Java 8 JDK installed.
>
> The artifacts will be generated in the lib directory. You can then
> execute ProGuard using the scripts in bin, for example:
>
> bin/proguard.sh
>
> You can publish the artifacts to your local Maven repository using:
>
> ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal

When I run `bin/proguard.sh` it says: `rror: Unable to access jarfile /home/myusername/proguard/bin/../lib/proguard.jar` The `lib` directory doesn't exist.

I have `openjdk-8-jdk` installed on Debian.

Comment: They seem to assume that you know how to use gradle. Run `./gradlew package` to trigger the build. But also: to use it you shouldn't need to build it from scratch. Use the gradle plugin or a binary distribution.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Using the binary distribution I could run it, but now it says `Error: You have to specify '-keep' options for the shrinking step.` I had to ignore warnings.